# Torque due to air resistance on a frisbee

Tags: drag, aerodynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

In my analytical mechanics course we worked out an example involving a disk (say, a frisbee) rotating after being thrown into the air. The disk experiences a torque proportional to its angular velocity ($\vec\tau=-c\vec\omega$) due to air resistance.

The exercise itself was simple (Euler's equations and a bit of elementary ODEs), but is the torque relation aerodynamically accurate?

Comment: Please could you provide more explanation of what you think and why?

Comment: Well, I have very little knowledge in aerodynamics, and I was just asking out of curiosity. I had tried to derive the relation by assuming that each particle in the disk experiences a linear drag and using the $\vec v=\vec\omega\times\vec r$ relation, but hadn't gotten very far.